# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module no Angular

Tags: angular

Estou tendo esse erro;

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Rei das
>   cochinhas/API/restaurantui/node_modules/primeng/components/inputtext/inputtext.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AdminModule in
>
> C:/Rei das cochinhas/API/restaurantui/src/app/admin/admin.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AdminModule in C:/Rei das
>   cochinhas/API/restaurantui/src/app/admin/admin.module.ts

Vou explicar quando acontece.

Eu ligo o computador e executo todos os serviços para rodar o sistema como MongoDb e Node Express, em seguida eu executo o Angular com o comando `ng server` depois que ele compila ele gera o erro em seguida;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Erro informa que o problema está no arquivo **AdminModule**, o que é muito estranho é que não existe nenhum erro nesse arquivo.
**Porém para minha aplicação subir eu tenho que simplesmente alterar qualquer coisa no arquivo, salvar e ele volta a funcionar e o erro desaparece.**

Mas que tipo de alteração eu faço no arquivo? É coisa do tipo  dar um espaço no arquivo sem alterar nenhum trecho de código.

Eu acho esse tipo de erro muito estranho, eu preciso corrigir mesmo que eu consiga evoluir esse projeto porque eu vou enviar-lo para o servidor na nuvem, e não posso ficar com ele assim;

Esse é o arquivo AdminModule;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MainComponent } from './restaurant/main/main.component';
import { ListComponent } from './restaurant/list/list.component';
import { AddComponent } from './restaurant/add/add.component';
import { EditComponent } from './restaurant/edit/edit.component';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './routes/admin-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AddmenuComponent } from './menu/addmenu/addmenu.component';
import { ListmenuComponent } from './menu/listmenu/listmenu.component';
import { EditmenuComponent } from './menu/editmenu/editmenu.component';

import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/components/inputtext/inputtext';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/components/button/button';
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/components/tooltip/tooltip';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    FormsModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
   // modulos de terceiros

   InputTextModule,
   ButtonModule,
   DataTableModule,
   TooltipModule

  ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent, 
    ListComponent, 
    AddComponent, 
    EditComponent,


    AddmenuComponent, 
    ListmenuComponent, 
    EditmenuComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    MainComponent, 
    ListComponent, 
    AddComponent, 
    EditComponent, 


    AddmenuComponent, 
    ListmenuComponent, 
    EditmenuComponent
  ], 

})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Precisando tirar dúvidas, estarei disponível.

Esse é meu arquivo package.json

```
{
  "name": "meat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.2",
    "admin-lte": "2.3.11",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "7.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

tentei mudar o @angular/cli está na versão "1.2.7" para 4.0.2, depois tentei, e rodei o **npm install** e gerou esse problema;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A sorte é que tenho uma versão anterior do projeto sem a modificação.

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar seu `package.json` para conferirmos as versões? A propósito, não querendo me intrometer, mas "coxinhas" é com `x`.

Comment: @Sorack obrigado pela diga de caligrafia, que eu escrevi rapido hahahah já vou atualizar minha postagem.

Comment: acabei de atualizar, pode ver meu arquivo  `package.json `

Comment: Seu `@angular/cli` está na versão "1.2.7" enquanto os demais estão na versão "4.0.2"

Comment: Devo mudar a versão de 1.2.7 para  4.0.2 ?

Comment: sim, muda pra vermos se é essa dependência que está com problema

Comment: eu fiz uma atualização da minha postagem poderia dar uma olhada.